# How to manage CSS style application order with React + Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set up a common pattern for managing styles in React - a "dumb" component has some default styles, and it also accepts the `className` prop in order to overwrite those individual styles.

However, I have been unable to implement this pattern successfully when using Material UI and its `makeStyles` method.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  child: {
    padding: 16,
  },
});

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent className={styles.child} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import mergeClasses from 'classnames';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  defaultStyles: {
    padding: 0,
  },
});

const ChildComponent = ({ className }) => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const mergedStyles = mergeClasses(className, styles.defaultStyles);
  return (
    <div className={mergedStyles} />
  );
};
```

In this example, no matter the order of arguments of `mergeClasses` in `ChildComponent`, the `defaultStyles` will always take priority over the `className` styles, and the `ChildComponent` `<div />` will render with 0 `padding`.

How do I use Material UI with this essential React pattern?

Comment: I would expect your example code to work with the order reversed. The material-ui components are probably using a [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) selector. Can you see what selectors are applying to the element in the browser?

Comment: The order in which classes are passed to `mergeClasses` has no bearing on which styles win. The only order that matters is the order of the style rules in the document (i.e. the order of the `<style>` elements in the `<head>`). This order is controlled by the order in which `makeStyles` is called -- a later `makeStyles` call will result in a later `<style>` element which should then win when [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is otherwise the same. Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Weirdly that's not actually the issue - the rendered class is "makeStyles-link-218 makeStyles-link-401", two equally specific selectors.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have attempted to reproduce the issue in a code sandbox as requested; weirdly, this issue reproduces here while working (the child has 0 padding), but when reloading the sandbox, it has 16px as desired. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-style-order-bc5rs

Comment: @RyanCogswell I do understand how `makeStyles` works in this way, but I would like to know how to use the parent-child-css pattern above (which is as core to React as anything) with MUI's `makeStyles` paradigm.

Comment: When you were working, did you edit the child styles last? If so, it would cause those newly edited styles to be tacked on to the end of the `<head>`. Reloading would then fix the order. That parent-child-css pattern should work just fine apart from transient issues while you're changing styles (and reloading the page should then fix it).

Comment: @RyanCogswell unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working that way in my application

Comment: How are you importing `ChildComponent` in your application?

Comment: @RyanCogswell `ChildComponent` is imported into `Components/index`, and `ParentComponent` imports `{ ChildComponent } from 'Components/index'`.

Comment: Is `ParentComponent` also in `Components/index`?

Comment: @RyanCogswell nope, it's outside the Components folder.

Comment: Without a reproduction of the issue, it's difficult to help.

Comment: @RyanCogswell yeah understandable, appreciate the effort

Comment: The key thing is the order in which the `makeStyles` calls happen. It should automatically happen in the appropriate order since `ParentComponent` would be importing `ChildComponent` (which would cause its `makeStyles` to be called). You could debug or put console logs right before the `makeStyles` calls to make check the order of execution. If you are using any lazy component loading, that could impact it.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I console.log()ed as recommended and the Parent `makeStyles` is being logged first.

Comment: Do you know why? Is the child component lazy loaded? Is the child `makeStyles` call not at the top-level?

Comment: @RyanCogswell the child is not lazy-loaded and all `makeStyles` invocations are top-level, yes

Comment: And Parent imports Child, but Parent `makeStyles` is executing before Child `makeStyles`? My only guess is that you have a somewhat circular dependency and that something that is imported in `Components/index` prior to Child is in turn importing Parent. I would check for all of the imports of Parent and see if any of those components which import Parent are imported (directly or indirectly) by `Components/index`.

Comment: Another way to check if a circular dependency may be the problem would be to see if the problem goes away if you import Child directly from Parent -- bypassing `Components/index`.